# I need to copy images from Linux server to my windows desktop, should i use threads? and how many?

Tags: multithreading, ssh

I need to copy between 400 - 5000 images, it changes every run.
how can i calculate how many threads will give me the fastest result?
should i open new SSH connection to each thread?

i use paramiko to open ssh connection.
and use sftp to copy the images.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess best solution before copying it's add images to one archive, because each time it's checks that each file copied and creating of new file it's very consumable operation.
If you will copy archive in one thread it's can have much faster speed of copying, because it's will not wait for each image copy.

So, will be much faster

1. pack to archive
2. copy
3. unpack

You can check it even without connection between any computers, just copy about 1 gb little files from one hard drive to another, and than pack these files into archive and copy again, you will notice that 2nd way will be muuuuuch faster